# segmentation fault when free() is used

Tags: c++, c, string

This code causes a Segmentation Fault:

```
int main(){

    char *p;
    char a[50] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    p = (char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));

    if(!p){
            cout << "Allocation Failure";
            cout << "\n";
    }
    else{
            cout << "Allocation Success";
            cout << "\n";
            p = a;
            cout << p;
            cout << "\n";
            free(p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output after executing this program is:

```
Allocation Success

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Segmentation fault
```

I am not able to find the bug. What may be reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're calling `free` on a block of memory that wasn't allocated using one of the `malloc` methods.

When you do: `p = a` you're assigning to `p` the memory used by the stack array `a`. That memory wasn't allocated using `malloc` and hence it can't be freed using `free`.

Furthermore with that re-assignment, you'll lose track of the block that you originally allocated with `malloc` and assigned to `p`, causing a memory leak.

Answer (score 12):

This:

```
p = a;
```

copies the *pointer*, not the contents of the pointed-to memory.  `p` now points at the first element of the array `a`.  So when you do `free(p)`, you're trying to free a non-dynamic array, which doesn't make any sense.<sup>1</sup>

You should investigate [`strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) to copy strings.

---

<sub>1. And it also causes a memory leak.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`char a[50]` allocates an array of fifty characters on the stack. `a` therefore points at an address on the stack.

`p = a` sets *p* to point at the same address as *a*. Therefore after `p = a`, p points at an address on the stack. Remember, *p* contains an *address*.

Afterwards, `free(p)` tries to free a region of memory on the stack, which is illegal. You can only free memory you got from malloc().

Answer (score 0):

you actually meant memcpy(p,a,50); not p=a, remember C does not have a string data type.

Comment: While you provide insightful help, be sure to answer the question too.

Answer (score 0):

```
p = a; // p points a
```

Executing this line, p should be pointing to const string (`char *`).
You cannot `free()` anything that is not obtained by calling `malloc` or `calloc`. Since in this example you try to `free()` a const string, you get an error.